# problem with array in php

Tags: php

i am starting learning php.

i saw this statement in `php.net`

```
$arr = array("somearray" => array(6 => 5, 13 => 9, "a" => 42));//problem in this line
```

but when i entered it in `phpdesigner7` it has error.

```
`syntax error unexpected T_variable`.
```

this is part of my code.

```
    $g = "f1";
 $g();
 f1("mehdi");
 print_r(gd_info());
 print "<br>"

$user = array("salam","marde","monen",12);//problem in this line
for($a = 1; $a<4; $a++)
{
    print $user[a]."<br>";
    $a++;
}
```

this has error too.

```
i find out the problem.if i write g(); it have error but with out it doesn't have error.but g(); alone dosn't have error why?
```

g(); alone dosn't have error why?

Comment: Can you please paste the error?

Comment: var_dump( $arr) works fine as standard PHP on Win32. What is the error?

Comment: I've seen your edit. The exposition of the problem is too "confused" and the testcase provided is not self-contained. I'm sorry to tell you that you won't get help with this kind of questions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with phpdesigner7, not the code.  That code is perfectly legitimate.

Answer (score 1):

The array itself is fine. It sounds most likely that you haven't included it properly inside the open/closing PHP tags, i.e.

```
<?php

$arr = array("somearray" => array(6 => 5, 13 => 9, "a" => 42));

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

9 times out of 10 the issue in on the line above the line quoted, look above the array you will see:

```
print "<br>"
```

(missing semi-colon)